# Where is the Azure Web App database?

Tags: asp.net, database, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

I been following a Microsoft tutorial on Azure Web Apps:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-webforms-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

I created a Web App on Azure then created the website in VS 2013 on my PC with authentication all working. I then tried to publish the website onto Azure. When I go through the publishing steps, I do not get a connection string. I have tried waiting (24 hours) and looked around the app to see if there are any settings, but I cannot find a way to get a connections string. Everything other than the login-in works.

I know I selected a free 20Mb database, but I cannot see any sign of one on the Azure portal. I created a second Azure Web app and it is exactly the same.

Where would I find the Azure app database (in the Azure Portal) used for storing the username & password? Any idea how I can get the login to work in the Azure cloud?

Answer (score 2):

So long you shouldn't have to wait. I just tried it and had the free DB after two minutes.

You find all SQL Server databases incl. the free one in the SQL Server section. That's the icon on the left with the container and the "DB" in front. There you should find your new database. Click on it, switch to the dashboard and on the right you find the section "quick glance". Click on the link "Show connection string" and copy from there what you need.

Btw, you should not be able to create a second free SQL DB. If you're allowed to create "second" free SQL DB, than there is no first one. That would definitely mean there went something wrong in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this really helped. I am not sure how, but the database has appeared. The database for the second app is still not showing. I played with a lot of settings as I got desperate, so not too sure what made the db appear.

Comment: BTW, I noticed that the Azure wizard does not always find my app. Logging in again appears to do the trick.

Comment: If you created these resources Web+SQL in the manage.windowsazure.com portal you should be able to look under **Linked Resources** whereas if you created the resources Web+SQL in the Preview Portal they will most likely be within the same **Resource Group.**

Answer (score 0):

While creating the website you would have specified the database server, db name etc. Under the sql db section this db will be listed. If you have done that way. then migrate the db that you have locally to azure using the migration wizard and then provide that azure sql db connection string in the web.config ( from where the connectionstring is used.) then the application should work fine.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but no db! Can you see the db in the Azure portal, if so please let me know where, so I can check.

Comment: I have got it working, please see the answer from Peter Kirchner. Thank you for you help.